# Cannot render component inside component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have really basic Vue app (on Rails):

hello_vue.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
import TurbolinksAdapter from 'vue-turbolinks'
Vue.use(TurbolinksAdapter)

import CollectionSet from '../collection_set.vue'

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { CollectionSet }
  })
})
```

collection_set.vue:

```
<script>
import Collectable from './collectable.vue'
export default {
  components: { Collectable }
}
</script>

<template>
  <p>test</p>
  <collectable />
</template>
```

collectable.vue:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'collectable'
}
</script>
<template>
  <p>test 2</p>
</template>
```

my webpage:

```html
<div id="app"><collection-set /></div>
```

With above example I don't see anything, but when I remove `<collectable />` from `collection_set.vue`, I see `test`. I don't have any errors.

Why `collectable` is not being rendered?

Comment: Have you exported collectable? collection_set might be not getting anything when importing Collectable otherwise.

Comment: @AnuradhaKumari In `collectable.vue` I have: `<script>export default { name: 'Collectable' }</script>`, do you mean it?

Comment: ah yes. Could it be an issue with casing. I see it names as  Collectable with capital 'C', but while using, we are using small case  <collectable />. Can you please verify on that

Comment: @AnuradhaKumari When I changed it to `collectable`, still nothing gets rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `template` code of collection_set.vue to

```
<template>
 <div>
    <p>test</p>
  <collectable />
</div>
</template>
```

the reason for error is that `Component template should contain exactly one root element`
Here we were trying to craete two root elements `p` and `collectable`

Now that I wrapped it within a parent `div` container, it works just fine.
Please try and let me know if it helps.

One suggestion is that always check into console of browser devtools to check what could be the issue. In this case, the console gave the exact error, also the code compilation failed with same error.

Comment: My hero, works! But now, why I do not get any error about not having one root element?

Comment: cool...Ideally you should have got error while serving the application itself, as the code compilation itself fails, also I got the same error in browser devtools.

Comment: I don't see anything in my browser devtools (chrome), do you know what can be the reason?

Comment: in console tab of devtools, check if all options from 'All Levels' dropdown are checked (specifically `error` option should be checked.)

Answer (score 0):

In Vue, each component must have only ONE root element, meaning you need to have a tag like `<p>` or `<div>` and inside it all your template.

Comment: But do you know why I could get no errors about more than one root element?

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is perhaps not working with a lint or the Vue Webtools extension... The best practice is to always have a root tag, suggesting ```<div>``` or ```<p>``` to every component.